# Condition for intersection of chords inside a circle?

Tags: circles

What is the condition for intersection of 2 chords inside a circle?

Given n number of chords how to find the number of pairs of interecting chords?

Comment: In what form are your chords initially given?  If they're written (uniquely!) in terms of pairs of points on the circumference of the circle, then it's easy to see that two chords intersect only if their points 'interleave' as you go around the circle.

Answer (score 0):

My try for $n=2$

Assume that the circle have ratio $r$ and is centered at $(0,0)$

Two chords with equations:
$$(r\cos{\theta_0},r\sin{\theta_0})+t(r\cos{\theta_1}-r\cos{\theta_0},r\sin{\theta_1}-r\sin{\theta_0}),0\leq t\leq 1$$
$$(r\cos{\theta_3},r\sin{\theta_3})+s(r\cos{\theta_3}-r\cos{\theta_2},r\sin{\theta_1}-r\sin{\theta_1}),0\leq s\leq 1$$

Have a intersection if:
$$(r\cos{\theta_0},r\sin{\theta_0})+t(r\cos{\theta_1}-r\cos{\theta_0},r\sin{\theta_1}-r\sin{\theta_0})=(r\cos{\theta_2},r\sin{\theta_2})+s(r\cos{\theta_3}-r\cos{\theta_2},r\sin{\theta_3}-r\sin{\theta_2})$$
Which is:
$$t(-\cos{\theta_0}+\cos{\theta_1})+s(\cos{\theta_2}-\cos{\theta_3})=\cos{\theta_2}-\cos{\theta_0}$$
$$t(-\sin{\theta_0}+\sin{\theta_1})+s(\sin{\theta_2}-\sin{\theta_3})=\sin{\theta_2}-\sin{\theta_0}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
     (-\cos{\theta_0}+\cos{\theta_1}) & (\cos{\theta_2}-\cos{\theta_3}) \\
     (-\sin{\theta_0}+\sin{\theta_1}) & (\sin{\theta_2}-\sin{\theta_3}) \\
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
     t \\
     s \\
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
     \cos{\theta_2}-\cos{\theta_0} \\
     \sin{\theta_2}-\sin{\theta_0} \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

The determinant is:

$$2 \sin{\left(\frac{\theta_0-\theta_1}{2}\right)} \left(\cos{\left(\frac{ \theta_0+\theta_1-2 \theta_2}{2}\right)}-\cos{\left(\frac{ \theta_0+\theta_1-2 \theta_3}{2}\right)}\right)$$
which must be non zero and the solution must be between $0$ and $1$ for each component.

Note: if the determinant is zero we can note that one possibility is $\theta_3=\theta_2$ or another $\theta_1=\theta_0$ (one of the chords is a point)